How to Ignore Missing Properties in AutoMapper During Update Requests?
I'm working on an update feature for my ShopOffer class. When updating, I want to ignore properties that are not included in the update request (i.e., the ones that are null). However, some properties like DiscountPercentage and TimesOfUsage still get mapped with default values (e.g., 0 or false) when they are null in the UpdateShopOfferRequestDto.
Here are my classes and mapping setup:
public class ShopOffer 
{
    public required string Code { get; set; }
    public required double DiscountPercentage { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; } = false;
    public required DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public required DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string? Type { get; set; }
}

public class UserSpecificShopOffer : ShopOffer
{
    public required string UserId { get; set; }
    public AppUser? User { get; set; }
    public required int TimesOfUsage { get; set; }
}

public class UpdateShopOfferRequestDto
{
    public double? DiscountPercentage { get; set; } = null;
    public bool? Active { get; set; } = null;
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; } = null;
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; } = null;
    public int? TimesOfUsage { get; set; } = null;
}

CreateMap<UpdateShopOfferRequestDto, UserSpecificShopOffer>()
    .IncludeBase<UpdateShopOfferRequestDto, ShopOffer>() // Reuse base mapping
    .ForAllMembers(opts =>
        opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null));

CreateMap<UpdateShopOfferRequestDto, ShopOffer>()
    .ForAllMembers(opts =>
        opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null)); // Only map non-null source properties

public async Task<ServiceResult<ShopOfferResponseDto>> Update(Guid id, UpdateShopOfferRequestDto offerDto)
{
    var offer = await shopOfferRepository.GetByIdAsync(id);
    if (offer == null) { 
        return ServiceResult<ShopOfferResponseDto>.BadRequest("Offer doesn't exist");
    }
    mapper.Map(offerDto, offer);
    shopOfferRepository.Update(offer);
    var result = await shopOfferRepository.SaveAsync();
    if (result <= 0)
    {
        return ServiceResult<ShopOfferResponseDto>.Failure("Failed to update offer");
    }
    var responseOfferDto = mapper.Map<ShopOfferResponseDto>(offer);
    return ServiceResult<ShopOfferResponseDto>.Ok("Offer updated successfully", responseOfferDto);
}

Values of TimesOfUsage and DiscpuntPercentage in offerDto before mapping are null
Issue:
Despite using ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Condition(...)) to only map non-null properties, I’m still getting default values for properties like DiscountPercentage and TimesOfUsage. They are getting mapped to 0 instead of staying unchanged when the source value is null.
What I've Tried:
I used .ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null)) in my mapping profile to avoid mapping null values.
I tried both including and excluding IncludeBase for the ShopOffer class.
Expected Behavior:
I want the null properties in UpdateShopOfferRequestDto to be ignored during mapping, meaning that only properties that are not null should be updated on the target object (UserSpecificShopOffer or ShopOffer).
